# Location Manager not working iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, cllocationmanager

```
[locationManager StarUpdatingLocation]
```

doesnt work in my case. I have an NSOBject class in which i have a method like this.

```
(void)findlocation
{
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init] ;
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Then I have the delegate methods

```
 (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation    *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

However using an NSLog statement i figured that the startupdating location method doesnt go into this locationmanager method. :( I am calling the current location method in another method in the same class so i would be saying [self currentLocation]. Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: are you running your `findlocation` method on your main thread or on a background thread?

Comment: Im not sure but i think its the main thread. At the bottom of xcode it says thread 1 so im assuming main thread? However basically i have a table view controller which calls a method called getlocationlist from a class called location and the method getlocationlist calls the findlocation method. Im new to this so im guessing main thread?

Comment: I could have sworn I saw another answer here a moment ago which included this great suggestion --> if you implement the delegate method `[CLLocationManager locationManager: didFailWithError:]` does that method get called?

Comment: No it doesnt. I did implement the didfailwitherror as well. Doesnt go into that either. yes there was another response and i cant find it too! and I didnt delete it :D

Comment: have you included CLLocationManagerDelegate into your .h file?

Comment: I just have this strong feeling that the delegate object is not receiving events or getting any CPU time.  Here's how to determine if you're on the main thread or not... in your findLocation, see if `[NSThread isMainThread]` returns true.

Comment: Okay will do that and return. Oh yes i have included CLLocationManagerDelegate in my .h file.

Comment: if you get any use ful answer then share you answer with other..:-)

Answer (score 0):

- Conform to protocol `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in your Class where you have this code.
- If this is the case, then you should see whether or not this code is working fine in Device. I think you are running this in simulator & the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` is not fired & getting upset on code.

If you are using simulator then by default the location of Simulator is set to None. 
Kindly check.

- Click on Simulator
- Check the Debug menu on top of desktop.
- Go to Location Submenu
- Check for the selected option. If it is none, then choose a custom location. Add values in latitude & longitude. (ex: 13.0524139 , 80.2480755)

If this works then you are good to go in simulator as well.

hope that helps.